# Detect touch on UIImageView in a CustomCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

i have custom UITableViewCell, i have subclassed the UITableViewCell:

MyCustomCell.h

```
MyCustomCell:UITableViewCell
```

and then i have also a xib file for this custom cell, all work fine, i can show all information, and image i have added on the cell, but i want detect a touch when the user touch on the uiimageview, so i have tried in this way:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MasterView";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[MasterViewCell alloc] init];
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MasterViewCustomCellImage" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = (MasterViewCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
    //NSLog(@"Nuova Cella");
}

[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

return cell;
}

 - (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImageView *thumbnailImage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1007];
[thumbnailImage setImage:[managedObject valueForKey:@"myImage"]];

if (thumbnailImage) {

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(detectTouchImage)];
    [longPress setMinimumPressDuration:1.0];
    [thumbnailImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [thumbnailImage addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
}

 }

-(void)detectTouchImage
{
 NSLog(@"Image Pressed");
 }
```

but i can't understand why don't work, it enter in the thumbnailImage if, but there don't detect any gesture on the image...anyone can help me? i have tried it on ios 5 and ios 6, but don't work...

Comment: can you check a couple of things first. Firstly, does it enter the code: if(thumbnailImage). Can you do a check whether it actually reaches that code? And where is the method detectTouchImage?

Comment: sorry i have edited my question...

Comment: add NSLog after 'if (thumbnailImage) {' line to see if you actually attach Gesture Recognizer. Do you understand difference between UILongPressGestureRecognizer and UITapGestureRecognizer?

Comment: yes, i have try to insert a debug point, and enter in that if statement, so it enter in, and i know the defference between a single tap gesture and a long pressure, i have also tried to use a single uitabgesture, but don't work...

Comment: do you declare -(void)detectTouchImage in .h? if not, add declaration or just move method in .m before  - (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath.

Comment: it's in .h and before the configure cell, in don't think so this is the problem...

Comment: 1) What is exactly in your nibfile named `MasterViewCustomCellImag`?  
2) Why do you init a `MasterViewCell` just to overwrite it two lines later?  
3) Is there a view with the tag `1007`? Is that view a direct subview of the cell? Or perhaps of `cell.contentView`?

Comment: By the way, you really don't need line cell = [[MasterViewCell alloc] init];

Comment: try setting `thumbnailImage .userInteractionEnable = YES;`

Comment: Ok you have right, i have deleted cell = [[MasterViewCell alloc] init]; then in my nibfile i have one image and some label, and the tag is connected to a UIImageView, and work, because i can display the image in the cell, and also the label connected with other tag, maybe the problem is that i have subclassed the UITableViewCell so i have a MyCustomCell.h and MyCustomCell.m that i need to use this: https://github.com/thermogl/TISwipeableTableView

Comment: Pitiero, I understand, suggestions might seem stupid. Just give it a try. Both target method signatures, without parameter and with one parameter should work. Just try to see if something change. Try declare -(void)detectTouchImage:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer; And add colon in @selector(detectTouchImage:)

Comment: @ValeriyVan i have tried don't work..

Comment: @George i have tried don't work

Comment: What if you use a button instead of an image view? And set selectors for `touchDownInside` and `touchUpInside` and then check the time difference to see if it was long enough to consider it a long tap?

Comment: @George yes maybe it's the only choice...

Comment: @Piero, check my answer with GitHub reference. It has completely working example. Check it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just made test project to verify where is the problem.
Completely working example is [here](https://github.com/valeriyvan/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_test) on GitHub. Download and play with it. TableViewCell has custom UIImageView with UILongPressGestureRecognizer attached to it. Everything is working just fine. Long press on any image and UIIAllertView pops up. So, your code with UILongPressGestureRecognizer seems to be OK. Problems is in some other part of your project which you don't expose.

Comment: i have tried your sample, but i can see any image on the row :( or label, there is only a uitableview...

Comment: @Piero, did you download whole project? It has 53*2 images in it. I downloaded it to check. It's OK.

Comment: @Piero, I modified project: label with cell number added, detailLabel with filename added, absence of file is detected now. Clone and run it.

Comment: i'm sorry for the late answer, thank you for the sample, it was very useful, but in my code i do it as you do, and don't work, but i have found the problem, in my code i use https://github.com/thermogl/TISwipeableTableView this project, and the problem is that :)...thanks anyway!

Comment: @Piero, at least you know now which part of your code not to blame.

Comment: @Piero hi Piero, do you know the reason now?  I have the same problem, and i use the swipeabletableview also.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most probably that the cell is highjacking the touches. Can you check whether your `didSelectCellForRow` method is getting called or the row is highlighted when you tap it? Also try to assign the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to the cell rather than the image.
If that works but you want to invoke the tap only when the thumb image is tapped you can use the `locationInView` method implemented in the `UIGestureRecognizer` class to see where exactly the user has tapped.

Comment: when i click the cell is highlighted and enter in didselectcellrow, if i do this: [cell addGestureRecognizer:tapped]; don't work with the long press gesture...

Comment: I am not sure how you create the `tapped` recognizer. Try creating and setting it like this: `UILongPressGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(detectTouchImage)];
    [tapped setMinimumPressDuration:1];
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:tapped];`

Comment: Can you remove the custom cell creation code and just create a generic cell with the gesture recognizer - `UITableViewCell * cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    return cell;` and see if that works for you.